# How to assert an IEnumerable parameter where order is unimportant?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm writing a unit test, I want to ensure that a particular method is called with some parameters:

```
var myMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyService>();
```

IMyService has a method on it with the signature

```
public bool SomeMethod(IEnumerable<string> values)
```

I have a business logic layer which consumes my mock

```
public class BusinessLogic
{
  protected MyMock MyMock{get;set;}

  public BusinessLogic (myMock)
  {
    this.MyMock = myMock;
  }

  public bool DoLogic()
  {
    var myCollection = // loaded from somewhere
    return this.MyMock(myCollection);
  }
}
```

I want to test the DoLogic method by making sure that it calls SomeMethod properly. However I have no control (and don't really want it over the ordering of the collection).

I want to assert that the method `SomeMethod` is called with the IEnumerable `{"a", "b", "c"}`  but I don't care on the order.

So far I have

```
myMock.Expect(x => x.MyMethod(new string[]{"a", "b", "c"});
```

and

```
myMock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.MyMethod(new string[]{"a", "b", "c"});
```

But this will fail if it's called with `{"b", "a", "c"}`. I don't want to change my business logic to ensure the ordering of the parameters (as this would design the BLL around the tests).

How can I assert this method call?

Comment: For the purposes of tests it doesn't matter what order you test it with, so simply `Expect` and `Assert` in the same order.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth but if my BLL passes in the collection in a different order won't it fail the test?

Comment: So far as I can see you are mocking the call, so you are in control of the order... Unless I missed something in the question. My comment was based on the fact you were controlling the input as well as expectations on the output. If you are not controlling the input then my comment is moot. Sorry, I wasn't very clear on that part.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth thanks for your help, I've tried to expand to show exactly the class I'm trying to test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Arg<T>.Matches`:

```
myMock.Expect(x => x.MyMethod(Arg<IEnumerable<string>>.Matches(s => !s.Except(expected).Any() && !expected.Except(s).Any()));
```

Comment: alternatively `expected.All(e => calledWith.Contains(e))` if you don't want duplicates check the count as well.

Answer (score -1):

Test frameworks usually have assertions for such matching, you can mix those two. Example with NUnit's `EquivalentTo`:

```
myMock.Expect(x => x.MyMethod(Arg<IEnumerable<string>>.Matches(value => 
{
    Assert.That(value, Is.EquivalentTo(new[] { "c", "b", "a" }));
    return true;
}));
```

This way, produced error message should be more descriptive than what Rhino will generate.

Comment: That actually won't compile. `Matches` takes an expression tree, not a delegate.